# Providing From Azure to Snow not working but Azure say it does

Tags: azure, servicenow

Hello guys I have an issue when i try to provide Users from Azure to Servicenow, the strange part about it is that Azure side it says that the providing is done and complete but i cannot see any of thoses user in my Servicenow instance. For information with the SAME proces Azure side AND Snow side, it worked for MULTIPLES groups of users

I have tried it with other groups of user and it work: at the moment 4 out of 11 groups are correctly provided, on snow, for the 7 other providing is "done" Azure side but i cant find any of thoses users in snow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.